# Simple_form_for time range

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml

i'd like to change minutes range. I have in haml:

```
= f.input :open_from, :as => :time, :label => "open from:"
```

and i want minutes only 0, 15, 30, 45, not 0..59. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleForm delegates the input generation to Rais time_select method. As you can see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dbbf198f5c2484f2b2cf32e7ec03f2d811775247/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L233-234), you can pass a :minute_step options to input call. Like this:

```
= f.input :open_from, :as => :time, :label => "open from:", :minute_step => 15
```